# How can I perfom an update with jena fuseki?

Tags: jena

I've wrote this query that normally works

```java
String query2 = "PREFIX publ: <http://www.ps7-wia2.com/publications/>\n" +
                "PREFIX pub: <http://www.ps7-wia2.com/publications#>" +
                "DELETE { publ: " + id + " pub:like ?o }\n" +
                "INSERT { publ: " + id + " pub:like " + nbLikes + " }\n" +
                "WHERE {publ:" + id + " pub:like ?o .}\n";

        RDFConnection conn2 = RDFConnectionFactory.connect(DATABASE);
        QueryExecution qExec2 = conn2.query(query2) ;
        conn2.close();
        qExec2.close();
```

And when I execute I encounter this error

````
org.apache.jena.query.QueryParseException: Encountered " "delete" "DELETE "" at line 2, column 52.
Was expecting one of:
    "base" ...
    "prefix" ...
    "select" ...
    "json" ...
    "describe" ...
    "construct" ...
    "ask" ...
    ```
````

Answer (score 0):

In SPARQL, query and update are parsed separately; they are separate languages which use many of the same elements but have different syntax for their functionality ("SELECT" vs "INSERT" etc).

Use `update(...)`.

Comment: mean that I get this result org.apache.jena.query.QueryParseException: Lexical error at line 2, column 58.  Encountered: " " (32), after : "UPDATE"

Comment: The request (that isn't shown) is illegal syntax.You need to call the right operation: `QueryExecution qExec2 = conn2.update(...)` See https://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/rdfconnection/org/apache/jena/rdfconnection/RDFConnection.html#update-java.lang.String-